# Generate dynamic data to pdf from web application

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, printing

I am using "Spring MVC" web application and I need to generate a small 'PDF' file and send it to the printer. Generated 'PDF' will contain user information that can get from accessing the database.

Are there any open source tools that I can use for this ? I looked at 'Java Print API' but still did not came across with a proper solution.

Can anyone please give some guidance?

actually from the web app (spring mvc) lets say i clicked "Do Print Job" button and without showing print dialog ( windows print dialog) can i do printing in the background? assuming using the default printer ?

Answer (score 2):

Look into Apache FOP, iText, and PDFBox... they should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

BIRT (http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) is a great solution for that kind of stuff. You can use it as separate servlet or use the engine as a library in Your code.

Answer (score 1):

Jasper Reports is an excellent tool for doing exactly what you want.
[Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to generate a document in LaTeX and render it as PDF. A bit ugly because it requires running external apps instead of just calling library functions, but you can do almost anything with regard to formatting and the PDF has a distinct touch (TeX fonts and text layout engine - a look I personally like very much).

Comment: Kosmulski - Thanks a lot for your answer.can you please provide me any link that i can go through about this "La Tex" tool?

Comment: LaTeX is a typesetting system - something like a word processor but more powerful (and not as easy to learn for the balance). It's popular especially for typesetting complex equations. The homepage is [here](http://www.latex-project.org/) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) gives some general information and a simple example. You should have packages easily available for any Linux distro out there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [iText](http://itextpdf.com/), [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) and [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/).  If you say more about your specific requirements then it might be more obvious about what would be the best options.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question. actually from the web app (spring mvc) lets say i clicked "Do Print Job" button and without showing print dialog ( windows print dialog) can i do printing  in the background? assuming using the default printer ?

Comment: Hi Sam.  I was only answering the "generate" part of the question - sorry about that.  Is your "Do Print Job" button in a browser page?  If so, this part of your question is about background printing from a web page.  Is that correct?

Comment: no problem jo..anyway thanks for the help. yes, button is on the jsp page. so when user click it can i do a background processing and generate a .PDF file and send it to the printer?

Comment: Hi Sam.  Looks like the way to go is to open a new window which generates the PDF (by calling a server/url), then call window.print(); in javascript.  Check  
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789803/print-a-pdf-via-javascript

Comment: Thanks for your help jo...i found a good example [here](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/01/spring-mvc-31-and-jasperreports-using_5116.html) currently i am following that tutorial. its on spring 3 and my project was based on spring 2.5. so i am doing some changes to embed this without annotations. Thanks again..