# How to print pdf portfolio in <object> tag using javascript or jQuery or ajax

Tags: javascript, jsp, pdf, printing, object-tag

Below is my code in xhtml to embed the PDF portfolio:

```
    <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                    <object id="pdfViewer" type="application/pdf"
                        data="#{sessionScope.showPortfolioURL}" height="700px"
                        width="100%"> </object>
                </h:panelGroup>
```

Could anybody please let me know how to print the PDF portfolio using javascript or jQuery or ajax on button click?
I have the Print option over my embedded PDF but I am not able to use it since I have requirement to mark the entry in database once someone tried to print it. So I will have to make a back-end call from the same JS function. If you know anyway through primefaces then it would be great but I think there is none.

If there is any way I can call embedded Adobe Portfolio's default Print functionality from my application through Javascript or something then that would also do for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print Pdf from javascript embed tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835648/print-pdf-from-javascript-embed-tag)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the answer referenced above. PDF Portfolios are quite different from generic PDF. They are a single PDF "Cover Sheet" with any number of PDF (or other file type) attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Solution may be to use 3rd-party pdf library as viewer and intercept print functionality to do your own job beforehand.
You can use Mozilla's [`pdf.js`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) for example.

Comment: To be totally honest with you, I gave up trying it bc I did not understand properly on how to use that. I could not understand if it's a custom made framework in itself or just a js file does all the things.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to print a PDF Portfolio from an application that doesn't understand what one actually is, generally meaning anything except Acrobat or Adobe Reader, you'll likely just get the cover sheet which is the base PDF that the Portfolio items are attached to.

What you'll need to do is use the library to burst the Portfolio into individual PDF files and print those. In those cases, most libraries that can print will be able to handle the separate PDFs. Note that all items in a Portfolio are not necessarily PDF, they could be anything really.

Comment: That's correct. Is there any way I can make Adobe Reader print icon work from my application? Like any javascript or JQuery function throughwhich I can trigger the embedded portfolio print button.

Comment: Probably not. However, you can probably inject some script into the PDF that will cause it to print as soon as it's fully loaded. There's a pretty simple way to do it where the script isn't then stored in the PDF. If that's an option for you, I can describe how it's done.

Comment: As long as it satisfies my requirement I'm totally going for it. As I told I need to keep the javascript function in my control because I also want to call my managed bean function from that same javascript to disassemble the portfolio and record the entry in DB that portfolio was printed. If I would be able to do all these things then yes I am all good. Sorry for this but sometimes requirements are totally insane. I hope you understand. :)

Comment: Ok - So the solution requires you use a browser that allows for Adobe Reader to be called as a plugin, it won't work with anything else. Unfortunately, that also mean it won't work with any modern browser. Still interested?

Comment: If you can't guarantee that Adobe Reader (or Acrobat) is the viewer, your best bet is to just put a big fat "Print PDF" button under the displayed PDF. If you can guarantee that Adobe Reader is the viewer, then you can use FDF or XFDF to run some JavaScript that will execute the print menu item. In that case, you're not going to link to the PDF, you'll link to the FDF and it will open the PDF and execute the JavaScript. Google the "Adobe FDF Toolkit" and read the Forms Systems Implementation document for information on how that works.

Comment: I'd be more specific but a comment doesn't allow the length needed and I can't in good conscience recommend this method as an answer.

Comment: Yes, we will be using Adobe Reader as the viewer. In this case do you have any other solution?

Comment: You could add a call to your backend to the document "willPrint" event. Then you don't need to try to trap events within the Object tag.