# could we able to listen browsers pdf viewer print action via callback in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I am loading a pdf content in chrome browser. Just forming  tag with appropriate src, and gets loaded with PDF container in the browser.

And now, I need to attach JS event for print/download click action inside the pdf viewer.

Looked into this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11060206/5730167
This is listening only the parent window's print action. On printing the pdf content(which is in embed tag), the event is not captured at this point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print Pdf from javascript embed tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835648/print-pdf-from-javascript-embed-tag)