# How to embed a pdf in HTML and print that with cmd+p / ctrl+p

Tags: php, pdf, iframe, embed

I am trying to include a pdf file in my HTML page and allow users to print that by using cmd+p or ctrl+p.

Here is my code -

```
<html>
    <body>
          <p> I want to print this page with pdf  </p>
          <iframe src="/my.pdf" width="800px" height="2100px" />
    </body>
<html>
```

When I visit my page I am able to see the pdf file but when I try to print it shows me a blank page for pdf.

I am building this application with PHP. I have tried the embed and object tag also but had no luck with this.

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such functionality is not possible as explained here: [Print Pdf from javascript embed tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835648/print-pdf-from-javascript-embed-tag#answer-27047664)

The only real thing you can do is try to convert the PDF to images and use the "@media print" tag to style the printing page appropiately.

Answer (score 0):

It's a different matter
Record it for others.

If there are a lot of blank pages, the class you want to print out:

```
@media print{
.paper {
display:inline-block
}
}
```

Apply above CSS. My problem solve by this trick.